# How to add convolution layer to custom estimator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I made a basic custom estimator for classifying short texts.

It's pretty much lifted from tutorial on www.tensorflow.org, with few minor changes, mostly for easier tweaking.

The feature column is categorical_column_with_hashbucket, wrapped in embedding_column.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_hash_bucket

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column

```
def text_classifier(
features, # This is batch_features from input_fn
labels,   # This is batch_labels from input_fn
mode,     # An instance of tf.estimator.ModeKeys
params):  # Additional configuration

# Use `input_layer` to apply the feature columns.

net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(
    features, 
    feature_columns=params['feature_columns'])

if params['dropout']:
            net = tf.layers.dropout(net,rate=0.0001,training=True)
# Build the hidden layers, sized according to the 'hidden_units' param.
try:
    activation=params['activation']
except KeyError:
    activation=tf.nn.relu
if 'hidden_dense_units' in params:
    for units in params['hidden_dense_units']:
        net = tf.layers.dense(net,
                    units=units,
                    activation=activation,
                    kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer()
                    )
        #Dropout layer
        if params['dropout']:
            net = tf.layers.dropout(net,rate=0.5,training=True)
        #Normalization
        if params['normalization']:
            net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                net,
                momentum=0.999,
                training=True
                )

# Compute logits (1 per class).
logits = tf.layers.dense(net, params['n_classes'], activation=None)

# Compute predictions.
predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    predictions = {
        'class_ids': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
        'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits),
        'logits': logits,
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

# Compute loss. 
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

# Compute evaluation metrics.
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                                predictions=predicted_classes,
                                name='acc_op')

metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}

tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

#Training OP
assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

#Initiating optimizer
try:
    optimizer = params['optimizer']
except KeyError:
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)

train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

After reaching, what I assumed to be, best possible performance of roughly 0.6 accuracy on testing dataset. I decided to add one dimensional convolution layer from Tensorflow library.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv1d

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't specify, that it requires 3 dimensional tensor as an input. If I simply use the input_layer as it's input, for example like this:

```
net = tf.layers.conv1d(net,filters=1,kernel_size=1)
```

I get following exception:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 1024]
```

The 1024 is embedding dimension btw, but it doesn't matter how large it is, the process crashes anyway.

I could expand the tensor, adding dimension like so:

```
more_dim = tf.expand_dims(input=net,axis=-1)
net = tf.layers.conv1d(more_dim,filters=1,kernel_size=1)
```

But that only gives me another exception, this time when computing softmax cross entropy loss:

```
ValueError("Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 18 for 'sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,1024,18].",)
```

The last dimension, 18, is number of labels. I could resize the tensor again. But I feel like it might be a loss of time.

And since my, admitedly naive, approach doesn't work. I have to ask, how to do it properly.

Comment: To those reading this question. The current version of tensorflow is more suited towards work with Keras layers and utilities. Use them instead, if possible, to avoid hiccups like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Tensorflow requires an additional channel dimension. Try

```
net = tf.expand_dims(net, -1) # Adding a channel as last dimension.
net = tf.layers.conv1d(net,filters=1,kernel_size=1)
```

Comment: It does work with 'filters=1', other values produce error on squeeze. For example: ValueError("Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for 'Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,254,4].",)

Comment: My bad. Remove the squeeze. Convolutional layers expand the last dimension. I updated the answer.

Comment: Eh, I already did that. That's actually what I started with. It results in: ValueError("Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 18 for 'sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,1024,18].",)

Comment: But if I add one convolutional layer with filter and kernel size 1, I get squeezable tensor. With essentially no loss of information.